# UIcollectionview not displaying data.The numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath methods are not firing.How to display data on label?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilabel, uicollectionview

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  departureTimesArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    User *user = [departureTimesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    if (!label)
    {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 90.0,90.0, 30.0)];
       label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:46.0/255.0 green:63.0/255.0 blue:81.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        label.tag = 100;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
    //    label.text=user.departureTime_Bus;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.departureTime_Bus];

    return cell;
}
```

Custom delegate method

```
-(void)repaint:(NSMutableArray *)retrievedData
{
    if (retrievedData.count > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@is the value",retrievedData);
        userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];

        [departureTimesArray addObjectsFromArray:retrievedData];
        [mycollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:departureTimesArray];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which ViewController is this? have you set the delegates properly?

Comment: hmm...Delegates are properly set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data source or delegate methods aren't firing, it's usually one of a few things:

1. Your data source or delegate for the collection view aren't set.
2. Your collection view is so small that a cell cannot fit in it. Both collection and table views only try to create the number of cells that it can display.
3. If you're using storyboards, make sure your view controller in the storyboard is actually referencing the file you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Check first  this

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController "<"UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource">"
```

Second thing is check `IBoutlet`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

Third one is check

```
self.collectionView.delegate=self;

self.collectionView.dataSource=self;
```

These three step must call for datasource and delegate method of collection view.